# Restoring database to a new server with a new name

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am trying to create backup and restore of a database to new server with new name using C# and SQL server database. I can create a backup of the database but I am not able to restore it to the new server using the new name.

My query looks something like this: it doesn't work and errors out:

```
RESTORE DATABASE test1 FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\BACKUP\setupdb\BackupForsetupdb.bak' 
WITH MOVE 'setupdb_Data' TO '\\newserver\e$\MSSQL\DATA\test1_Data.MDF', 
MOVE 'setupdb_log' TO '\\newserver\e$\MSSQL\DATA\test1_Log.LDF';
```

I am trying to achieve this through C# code.It looks like the database cannot be restored to the remote servers. Please throw some light on this.

Thanks!

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3):

You can't have SQL Server databases on network shares normally: local/SAN type drives only

The backup file can be on a share but the MDF and LDFs must be local

There is an [MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304261) on it: it can be done but **at your own risk**

Comment: You can do it.  I've configured a server to run dbs from a UNC path.  (Don't ask me why...)  Not saying its a good idea, but its possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your paths for the move command have to be relative to the server.

```
e:\MSSQL\Data\test1_data.mdf
```

And your restore from path has to be relative to the server as well.  If the `c:\` is from your local machine, you either need to point it to a UNC path (`\\yourpc\c$\...`) or move it to the server.  But be aware that if using the UNC path option, the user the server process is running as has to have permissions to access the share as well.  So you're probably better off copying to a drive on the remote computer.